# Android Kotlin Fingerprint - Binder has been finalized

Tags: android, kotlin, fingerprint

I'm having a problem handling fingerprint authentication using Kotlin. After the fingerprint authentication succeeds and the user logins, it always gives this exception:

```
E/System: Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer
E/System: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Binder has been finalized!
          at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
          at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:618)
          at android.security.IKeystoreService$Stub$Proxy.abort(IKeystoreService.java:1341)
          at android.security.KeyStore.abort(KeyStore.java:519)
          at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.finalize(AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:744)
          at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreUnauthenticatedAESCipherSpi$CBC$PKCS7Padding.finalize(AndroidKeyStoreUnauthenticatedAESCipherSpi.java)
          at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:224)
          at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:211)
          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:760)
```

I really don't understand why it is giving me this exception. The app doesn't close, it hasn't any problem. But as I'm kinda perfectionist i didn't want to have this error so I really would like if some of you can help me please :(

Comment: it does not come from your app - you have to live with it

Comment: @pskink so it is a device problem? :/

Comment: it looks so ...

Comment: @pskink well thanks anyway then :)

Comment: check the PID of the process - https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat.html#outputFormat, what is it?

Comment: @pskink for what purpose? I checked the logs and i think the PID is: 8769

Comment: so now launch `adb shell` and type `ps | grep 8769` - if you dont have `grep` on your device / emulator check the second column and find 8769 - for example for PID 157 the line is: `system    157   1     53028  2932  ffffffff b7646a23 S /system/bin/surfaceflinger`

Comment: @pskink Ok i'll try. I have never done anything with adb shell yet.

Comment: @pskink done. What's the purpose now?

Comment: so what app is a culprit? what is the output of `ps | grep 8769` ?

Comment: `u0_a800   16066 829   1883640 165564          0 0000000000 S`
well now it isn't 8769 but 16066 because i rebuilded the app, but what can I check with this? Is there a way to correct the problem with this data?

Comment: did you see my line: `system 157 1 53028 2932 ffffffff b7646a23 S /system/bin/surfaceflinger` here PID is 157 and the app that was run is `/system/bin/surfaceflinger` - you seem to cut off some parts